# How to hide keyboard after edittext click

Tags: android, dialog, keyboard, fragment

I have a edittext  in my android app where I can put a person birthdate. When I click on it a dialog fragment appears, but I have to click two times. After first click there is an keyboard and I don't want it.

I know that I can use button instead, but i prefer editext, because it looks better :)
How can I change it? Can I open diagram in first edittext click? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Context? Fragment suggest android but is still pretty ambitious. Might help to mention what your working with...

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's an android app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your EditText not focusable by adding `android:focusable="false"` in XML declaration and then use simple onClickListener on the EditText.

Else, you can also use the following method to hide the keyboard:

```
public void hideSoftKeyBoard(Activity activity) {
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

This can be invoked as follows:
`hideSoftKeyBoard(this)` from an activity or `hideSoftKeyBoard(getActivity())` from a fragment.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works somehow, but not perfect. When I click first time on editext, keyboard appears, but in second click keyboard is hidden. Can I open my dialog on first click somehow?

Comment: Can you not use a simple onclicklistener on EditText if you really want to use Edittext?

Comment: Make your EditText no focusable by adding    android:focusable="false" in xml.